# How to broadcast live to icecast using java?

Tags: java, mp3, icecast

I can broadcast an mp3-file to icecast using jShout.
MP3SPI tells that it can broadcast mp3-files to icecast.

But how can i broadcast liveaudio from my soundcard as mp3 to icecast in java?

- Right now capturing audio this way: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/capturing.html
- Right now sending mp3-files to icecast with: jshout

Comment: What are you having trouble with?  Encoding the MP3 stream?  Opening a socket to Icecast?  Handling metadata?  You need to be much more specific if you expect a useful reply.  Read the FAQ:  http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: I want to stream audio from my soundcard (microphone) to the icecast server. Ogg would be fine for me, but mp3 better.

Comment: Hi, I know this is an old post, but did you figure out how to do that? I'd be happy to have a piece of code or tips. Cheers.

Comment: No i did not, still hope to get an well documentated examople from a-z of how to stream live audio from java or using some api in java ...